# Is nodeIndex a valid DOM element property in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, nodes

I came across some javascript at work today that used [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to fetch two elements. It then used elem.nodeIndex to determine the position in the elements parent for each element. Nothing is setting this property anywhere and I do now see a reference to it in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533055(VS.85).aspx), [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Properties), or anywhere else.

I stepped through this javascript in [FireFox](http://getfirebug.com/) with [FireBug](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2382a66a1ce9edf6/168046b517318240?lnk=gst&q=nodeIndex#168046b517318240) and tested the code in chrome and opera. I am sure nothing was trying to set this property. However, I can't find any information on this nodeIndex property anywhere.

Does nodeIndex exist as a DOM property in IE, or did I miss something while debugging my code?

**UPDATE:** I asked the same question on the [jQuery list](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2382a66a1ce9edf6/168046b517318240?lnk=gst&q=nodeIndex#168046b517318240) and they confirmed the property is for internal use only.:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's jQuery that's [adding `nodeIndex` to nodes in some cases](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/selector.js#L592).

Comment: I asked on the jQuery list and apparently this is only intended for internal use.
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2382a66a1ce9edf6/168046b517318240#168046b517318240

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easy answer is: If it isn't documentated anywhere like MDC, MSDN or W3, then it isn't a 'real' DOM property.

The idea of using nodeIndex, is also wrong, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't "want to do that." The fact that it worked in IE, yet wasn't documented was what bothered me.